# How to define unique workspace for each branch in Multi branch build Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Freestyle multi-branch project to define a build for all branches in the project.
The problem is that if I use "Use custom workspace" I cannot define a path using ${branch} name.
I would like to do something like:
Use custom workspace: [dropfolder]\${branch}
But the ${branch} is not recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic variables when configuring workspace location.

You can however build multiple branches automatically, check i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344955/hudson-jenkins-git-build-all-branches) question.

Comment: Thanks. I' resolved the issue by post build batch XCOPY "C:\Projects\...\target\X.war" "C:\Projects\MyProject_Artifacts\%GIT_BRANCH%\" /D /C /R /I /K /Y

Comment: If you wanted to just keep the `*.war`, have a look into jenkins's functionality to archive build artifacts. Check out [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins)